# How to call API in Command Line Interface

Tags: json, api

I have an API URL which looks like this `https://my.domain.com/api/users`, but when i try to access it through web I got blank page,
and when i try `curl` i got nothing, how do i access it to view content of the users? I have `api_key` and `accessToken`

This is what i have done so far:

`curl https://my.domain.com/api/users`

I have an API URL which looks like this `https://my.domain.com/api/users`, but when i try to access it through web I got blank page,
and when i try `curl` i got nothing, how do i access it to view content of the users? I have `api_key` and `accessToken`

This is what i have done so far:

`curl https://my.domain.com/api/users`

Comment: You'll need to share details of your api implementation. Without any specifics (such as code, inputs, expected vs actual outputs, results from debugging, etc), there's really no way to help. Note: we don't even know what language you've written your api in, nor how you've deployed it. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: its zendesk API

Comment: Ok so... *edit your question* to show what you did with zendesk. And then edit your tags to include zendesk. Details like this are fairly important. But like I said in my last comment: *edit your question* - don't put additional important details in comments.